# No Procesó el Pago

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy realizando una pequeña prueba con mercadopago , para lo cual no estoy haciendo mas que usar los códigos que aparecen en la documentación para realizar un Checkout Básico.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.mercadopago.MP"%>
<%@page import="org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject"%>

<%
    MP mp = new MP("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET");
    mp.sandboxMode(true);
    String preferenceData = "..."; //Un Json como lo indica la documentacion

    JSONObject preference = mp.createPreference(preferenceData);

    String sandboxInitPoint = preference.getJSONObject("response").getString("sandbox_init_point");
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pay</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="<%= sandboxInitPoint %>">Pay</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Redirecciono al SandBox de manera satisfactoria, sin embargo por mas que utilizo las Tarjetas de Crédito de Prueba para obtener un pago satisfactorio no lo consigo, se muestra un mensaje de que: No se procesó el Pago. Y al usar otros medios de pago como tarjeta de débito se muestra: Tuvimos un problema intenta nuevamente. ¿Alguna idea? Muchas Gracias.